# How do you choose MAX or MIN values from a range of incomplete data?

Tags: modeling, excel

I am currently working with large datasets that have missing data points. My data ranges from the years 1979-2009. I want to choose, by year, the maximum value from that year. Missing values are replaced with a "."

I am currently using the formula:

```
{=MAX((E13:E2863=1979)*(H13:H2863))}
```

This array returns the max value where the appropriate data is available. However when i use the array over the entire dataset, a #VALUE error occurs within the box.

My question is how do you overcome this issue? Is there a way to develop a formula that will not take into account for the missing data points i.e. cells with "."

Below i will post a screenshot representing my spreadsheet/issue.

```
B       C    D     E     F =MAX((B6:B18=1979)*(E6:E18)) 
1979    0    53    67    38    
1979    0    57    72    41    
1979    0    63    .     47    
1979    0    64    79    49    
1979    0    65    78    52    
1979    0    57    71    43    
1980    0.37 43    52    33    
1980    0    47    60    34    
1980    0    55    70    39    
1980    0    64    79    48    
1980    0    66    82    50    
1980    0    69    87    51    
1981    0    71    85    57
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Quick and dirty: `=MAX(($B6:$B18=1979)*IF(ISTEXT(E6:E18), 0, E6:E18))`

Answer (score 2):

Using a Pivot Table isn't as quick or dirty, but may give you some more options for further analysis that make this approach worthwhile. I honestly have no idea how to convey in words how to use Excel's pivot tables, but if you highlight all of your data of interest and click on "insert --> pivot table" and then adjust the row labels and values, you can eventually get what you are after.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: arghh - my screenshot blocks half of the actual table, but I hope the point gets across. Pivot tables can do quite a bit in terms of aggregation, so can definitely be worth the time investment if you find yourself working with Excel on a regular basis.